# Best way to serve npm packages with django?

Tags: javascript, django, npm, webpack

I am using django as a backend with a few js packages installed with npm.  I am currently accessing the packages by allowing django to serve /node_modules by adding it to the STATICFILES_DIRS.  This has been working, but I have to go in the pacakge and find the js file I want to point to and then load it using a `<script src="{% static ...`.

This is a bit tedious and seems a bit "hacky." I also cannot figure out how to use imports/requires inside my js files.  Is there a way to use imports or am I stuck loading everyting via script tags?  I assume this is because django doesn't know how to server the npm packages appropriately?  I've read a bit into webpack and I'm still unsure if webpack is a solution to my problem. Any advice?

Comment: You really should bundle your JS files instead of the hack you're currently using. Webpack can be a little hard to grasp, especially if you're not familiar with JS bundling. I personnaly like to use ParcelJS, which needs no configuration at all. But yes, no matter the tool, you should really get into JS bundling

Comment: @blex do you know if it is compatible with a django project?  I am using django templating, so the html isn't pure html

Comment: Bundlers like WebPack or ParcelJS, or Rollup, or Gulp... can be used independently from the rest of your project. The way to do it is different for all of them, but the process is the same: once you are ready to go to production, you `build` your JS, into a minified file, in the appropriate directory (which is exposed by Django). And your template references that minified file. You can either build by hand, or, if you have a deploy pipeline, automate this in the pipeline

Comment: There are ZERO good examples on how to use ParcelJS and Django. What is supposed to be a quick minor detail turns into a prolonged unanswerable nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend learning/using Webpack.

I was trying to avoid using it, but it's a great tool to have in your development bag.  Makes front-end development modular and simplistic.